# Consume kafka messages using shell scripts

Tags: shell, apache-kafka

I wrote a script to consume kaka messages to check if they can consume messages properly.

I just started learning shell scripts, I don't know if my scripts are rigorous?

Wanted to know if it's good practice to do that and what would be the best way to do that?

```
#!/bin/bash

path=/home/kafka/kafka

TOPIC=`$path/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list|grep -v "__consumer_offsets"|grep -m 1 "[a-zA-Z]"`

timeout -k 3s 3s $path/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic $TOPIC --from-beginning --max-messages 1 &>/dev/null

PETVAL=$?

if [ $PETVAL -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo  "The query was successful"
else
        echo  "The query failed"
fi
```

I also need to judge the version, because the query message in the lower version needs to add the parameter "--new-consumer".

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should give the option to set an external bootstrap server and zookeeper address

The Kafka CLI scripts don't have a way to ask the broker for versions. You should generally always use `--boostrap-server`, which overrides `--new-consumer` option

Comment: vesrion=`ps -ef|grep -v grep|grep -o "kafka.\{,20\}[0-9]-sources.jar"|awk -F '-' '{print $2}'|cut -d . -f 1,-3|tr -d .` if [ ${vesrion} -gt 0102 ]   That's what I do.